# react native navigate between screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am trying to to navigate between two screen but it does not work
here my code
when  i run the code it gives errors

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {MainPage, ListPage, DetailPage} from './pages';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainPage}  />
      <Stack.Screen name="List" component={ListPage} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailPage} />
      
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to following.

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {MainPage, ListPage, DetailPage} from './pages';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainPage}  />
        <Stack.Screen name="List" component={ListPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailPage} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

You can find more details on how to use Stack Navigator [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#api-definition).

Answer (score 0):

use  `<Stack.Navigator>` tag after `<NavigationContainer>` tag

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainPage}  />
    <Stack.Screen name="List" component={ListPage} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailPage} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```